# Hosted SharePoint to support OAuth/OpenID authentication?

Tags: authentication

Is it yet reasonably possible to integrate OAuth or OpenID authentication as a means of signing into SharePoint?

Preferably, any obsolete account management features would be entirely hidden away and we wouldn't be required to ALSO manually create a local SharePoint account and match it with the external account.  It should all be seamless, native or native-like functionality.

I have project sites that I want to invite people from other domains to participate in without requiring them to manage yet another username/password set.  Many CMS systems are allowing for this now through something like Janrain Engage and it would be excellent to be able to leverage the power of SharePoint in this scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenID Membership Provider is an ASP.Net Membership provider and login
>   control that is compatible with the OpenID Authentication 2.0
>   implementation.
>
> It allows you to quickly upgrade your ASP.Net 2.0 or SharePoint site
>   to take full advantage of OpenID.
>
> The OpenID Membership Provider can be used side by side with another
>   ASP.Net Membersip Provider. Users can choose how the want to log in.
>   OpenID accounts can be linked to existing accounts, users don't have
>   to create a new one.

You can get it from here: http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/

Things can't get more easier, hope it helps ;)

Or for help you can check this link out,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593652/how-to-get-openid-authentication-on-sharepoint-services